# Problems adding a vline to ggplot barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to add a vertical line to a ggplot barplot (x axis is continuous). One version works as I expected it to, a second version produces an error. I do not understand why.

Basically I have a vector ("alter") with some numbers, and I want to plot the frequencies of the values:

```
alter <- c(19, 23, 24, 31, 32, 43, 51, 54, 54)
alter.table <- table(alter) # add frequencies

alter.table.df <- data.frame(alter.table)
alter.table.df$alter <- as.numeric(as.character(alter.table.df$alter)) # convert from factor to numeric

alter.table.df$Freq <- as.numeric(alter.table.df$Freq)

alter.mean <- mean(alter, na.rm = T)
alter.md <- median(alter, na.rm = T)


library(ggplot2)
```

Version A) **does** work:

```
p <- ggplot(alter.table.df, aes(x = alter, y = Freq)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") 
p

p2 <- p + geom_vline(xintercept = alter.mean, colour = "red") +    geom_vline(xintercept = alter.md, colour = "blue") 
p2
```

Version B) does **not** work/produces error:

```
px <- ggplot(alter.table.df, aes(x = alter, y = Freq)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + geom_vline(xintercept = 37, colour = "red") + geom_vline(xintercept = 32, colour = "blue")
```

So, it appears if I add the geom_vlines seperately to a new plot, it works out. If I try to put it all in one plot, it fails. I do not understand what the problem is.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
Sebastian

Comment: Actually it works in my case, you probably need to call your object "px" again from the terminal (i.e., type in px and enter)

Comment: I just realized that it appears to be a line break issue: 'px <- ggplot(alter.table.df, aes(x = alter, y = Freq)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + geom_vline(xintercept = c(alter.mean, alter.md))' **does** work.  Whereas splitting the code in two lines does **not** work

Answer (score 2):

No need to call  `geom_vline` twice. You can just give a vector of values as input to `xintercept` Like

```
    px <- ggplot(alter.table.df, aes(x = alter, y = Freq)) + geom_bar(stat = 
"identity") + geom_vline(xintercept = c(37,32), colour = "red")
```